# Shifting the search bar to right of navigation bar

Tags: html, css, frontend, navbar, nav

I have the following piece of code. I want to shift the search bar on the right most side of the nav bar as well as I want to add a search icon with it. I already used the float:right property for search but to no use. How do I shift it to the right? Following is my HTML and CSS Code Respectively

HTML:

```
    <body>
    <header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul> 
                <li> <a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> About </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Services </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Products </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Contact Us </a></li>
                <li> <form class="form"> <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Search"> </form> </li>
             </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

And following is my CSS:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    background: #222;
    font-family: 'Work-Sans',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.container
{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header
{
    background: #f3e5ab;
}

header::after
{
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

nav
{
    float: left;
}

nav ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li  a
{
color: #444;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
}

nav a:hover
{

}


nav a::before
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #444;

    transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;


}
nav a:hover::before
{
    width: 100%;
}

form .form
{
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to position it.

Try:

```
ul li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 0;
}
  header {
    background: #f3e5ab;
    position: relative
  }
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2359/

Comment: Yes now it's shifted on the right however now it is not aligned with the other list items, How do I align it properly?

http://jsbin.com/temecuxuxu/edit?html,css,console,output

Comment: No man that has spoiled it even more :( But anyways thanx for effort  (:

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want.

Simply make the `.search-bar` float to the right. It will be on right in the expanded screen.

> To keep a search icon inside this, just make it position relative and add extra element like `<span class="search-icon"></span>` inside it. Make that position absolute.

```
.search-bar{
    position:relative;
}

.search-bar .search-icon{
    position:absolute;
    right: 5px; //adjust this
    top: 2px; //adjust this
}
```

```css
body
{
    margin: 0;
    background: #222;
    font-family: 'Work-Sans',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.container
{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header
{
    background: #f3e5ab;
}

header::after
{
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

nav
{
    float: left;
}

nav ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li  a
{
color: #444;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
}

nav a:hover
{

}


nav a::before
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #444;

    transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;


}
nav a:hover::before
{
    width: 100%;
}

form .form
{
    float: right;
}

.search-bar{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul> 
                <li> <a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> About </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Services </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Products </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Contact Us </a></li>
                <li class="search-bar"> <form class="form"> <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Search"> </form> </li>
             </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </header>
</body>
```